# Changing the default address in CANopen Protocol in TwinCAT 3

Tags: plc, twincat, canopen

I am currently working with a Beckhoff PLC model CX2030 and a Wago PLC model 750-838, using the El6751 module for CAN-open communication between them. In the Wago PLC, I have set up a series of I/O cards.

To establish the communication, I created an EDS file and configured the Mapping addresses as follows:

```
TPDOs:
1A00:01 >>>>>> A0C00110
1A00:02 >>>>>> A0C00110
...
1A03:04 >>>>>> A0C01010

RPDO:
1600:01 >>>>>> A5400110
1600:02 >>>>>> A5400210
1600:03 >>>>>> A5400310
```

The configuration seems to work fine until I activate TwinCAT3. However, once TwinCAT3 becomes active, the mapping addresses are automatically changed to default values.

I'm unsure why this is happening and how to resolve it. Can anyone provide insights on what might be causing the mapping address changes and how to prevent it from happening? Any suggestions or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Before Active TwinCAT3

[image]
After Active TwinCAT3
[image]